# How to restrict a directory that for logged in users only: Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, redirect

I have a directory in my project on the root, out side the application folder as follows.
localhost/my_project/my_directory
so how i can protect my_directory that only logged in users can access this and if anyone not logged in and direct access this direct it will be redirected to localhost/my_project "home page".

i have used this method but not worked:

```
<?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in'))  || $this->uri->segment(1) == 'my_directory'){
           redirect('homepage')
     }
```

Comment: i think this will help i guess [here](http://www.dialme.com/m/articles/view/How-to-Prevent-direct-access-to-files-and-folders)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think [HERE](http://www.htaccessredirect.net/) you can do what ever you want.

you gonna make .htaccess file in oldDirectory

```
//301 Redirect Entire Directory
RedirectMatch 301 /oldDirectory(.*) /NewDirectory/$1
```

i think you can rename the oldDirectory with the directory you need to prevent access and the NewDirectory to the login form i guess :)

and you can see [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/redirects/setting-up-a-301-permanent-redirect-via-htaccess) with files

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you may have an extra **)** and need a **;**

```
<?php if(!$this->session->userdata('logged_in') || 
         $this->uri->segment(1) == 'my_directory') {
           redirect('homepage');
     }
```

Comment: But actually i am not getting where i have to put this code.in controller i have to create a method then how i will trigger that method. this is the issue. @user2182349

Comment: @ShoaibFareed - This code would go in your **Controller**, or an extension thereof.